# How can I tell if someone else is logged into my Windows 10 PC?

Tags: windows, admin, remote-access

Three or four times recently, I've tried shutting down my Windows 10 PC, only for it (*mysteriously*) to instead go back to the normal Windows login screen. And when I *then* try to shut the PC down from there, it (*again mysteriously*) warns me that this will shut down any connected users' sessions (but without giving any useful details).

All of which makes suspect (in a slightly paranoid, but probably justified way) that someone else *might possibly* now be logging in to my PC from time to time.

**So: is there anything (i.e. application / trick / hack / whatever) I can use to find out / track who (or what) is currently (remotely) logged in to my Windows 10 PC?**

Because I work from home, I guess it's *conceivable* that a client company's firewall / antivirus bot is doing something nasty (but legit) that I'm unaware of. But... I'd just like to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `query user` in a command prompt. No need for elevation.